# inherit a function from one class to another in python?

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have a class calling two functions and two instance methods.

```
    class MyClass(object):
        def df1(self):
            raw_data = {'preTestScore': [4, 24, '', 2, 3],'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
            return df1

        def df2(self):
            raw_data = {'preTestScore': [14, 4, 15, 12, 13],'postTestScore': ['', 4, 7, 2, 7]}
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
            return df2

        def df1_and_df2(self):
            return (self.df1(), self.df2())
```

And how to inherit those two dfs from another class

```
  class MySecond():
       #call df1 and df2 from MyClass
       #work on from those two dfs
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make obvious sense. Methods can be called on objects -- not directly. Perhaps you want to have `MySecond` *inherit* from `MyClass`? If so, just Google "python inheritance"

Comment: it's not obvious why you would want to do this as is.  What do the classes represent?

Comment: Your methods are static methods, i.e. they don't use `self`. You can decorate them with `@staticmethod` and simply call them via `Myclass.df1()`. Not that this makes much more sense either.

Comment: Awesome, I get to share some resources on the **XY problem**: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377, http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: changed the question, as i was not sure about it.

Comment: what do your classes represent?  This does not appear to be the most intuitive code structure.  And it's totally unclear that inheritance is a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyClass.df1` and `MyClass.df2` methods are not depending on a `MyClass` object, meaning that they could be declared as static methods:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def df1():
        raw_data = {'preTestScore': [4, 24, '', 2, 3],'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
        return df1

    @staticmethod
    def df2():
        raw_data = {'preTestScore': [14, 4, 15, 12, 13],'postTestScore': ['', 4, 7, 2, 7]}
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
        return df2
```

From there they could be called directly from the class anywhere without requiring an instantiated object:

```
MyClass.df1()
MyClass.df2()
```

**EDIT:** To inherit from `MyClass`, you would do the following:

```
class MySecond(MyClass):
    pass
```

Now instantiating `MySecond` would inherits `MyClass` methods. E.g.

```
instance = MySecond()
instance.df1_and_df2()
```

More info about inheritance: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: How to inherit from one class to another?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class you could do

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.dfl()
obj.df2()
```

You could also have MySecond inherit MyClass by doing

```py
class MySecond(MyClass):
   #code
```

Comment: How to inherit from one class to another?